# Picking proper battery type for car with dashcam

Tags: battery, dashcam

My car has a 55D23R battery rated for 356 cold cranking amps (CCA) as recommended by the manufacturer. I installed a Blackvue DR750S-2CH dashcam which has a parking mode. The parking mode allows the camera to stay on and record video based on motion or vibration. The camera will shut itself off once the battery voltage drops below 12.0V. After a few weeks of using this camera, I've noticed that the battery can't keep the camera on for more than a few minutes after parking (initially it could go for approximately 12 hours).

**Will replacing the battery with a deep-cycle battery help? Will a higher CCA rating help? I'm looking for a battery that will keep my camera running without degrading the battery quickly.**

**Edit:** My battery's charge capacity is 48Ah. Average power consumption of the camera in parking mode is 300mA (3.6W at 12V).

I'd like to clarify the timeline since my original post was a bit vague. I installed the camera in July 2018 (2 years ago). In the first 2-3 months, the battery slowly degraded until the camera couldn't be powered for more than a few minutes while parked. I stopped using the parking feature and the battery has lasted fine until this month when I've noticed it's not holding a charge well. I plan to replace the battery very soon and would like to start using my dashcam in parking mode again.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: How many amps is the camera using? It shuold be really low in the mA range otherwise you will face problems. And, btw, CCA is not relevant here you need Ah.

Comment: If your voltage is below 12V on your battery so soon after stopping then your battery is on the way out and needs to be replaced, I doubt it has anything to do with the camera. However, I wouldn't trust the camera on this, I'd test the battery directly with a multimeter before spending any money.

Comment: Apparently [that battery](https://www.tayna.co.uk/car-batteries/jis/55d23/) has a capacity of 60 Ah.

Comment: @SolarMike, WeatherVane, and GdD I added additional info to the post to clarify your comments. Paulster2 thanks! Excited to join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of internet research, I've learned that this problem is typical of dashcam owners who use parking mode. There are three main options of addressing the issue.

## Option 1: Dedicated Battery Pack

There are battery packs specifically designed to power dashcams which fit under front seats or in glove compartments. However, these battery packs typically cost $200-$300.

Here's a list of some dedicated battery packs from u/random12356622 on a similar [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Dashcam/comments/87g0im/best_car_batteries_for_dashcam_dr750s2ch_with/) post:

> - Cellink Battery B 2nd Generation ($219.99 USD)
> - Cellink Battery NEO ($309.99 USD)
> - BlackVue Power Magic B-112 Battery Pack ($154.99 USD)

## Option 2: Deep Cycle Battery

Since my battery is regularly drained to 12.0V, it is best to use a deep cycle automotive battery. A common deep cycle battery is the Absorbent Glass Mat (AGM) type [1]. Use an AGM battery with the highest possible capacity to allow for longer use of the camera parking mode. Here are a few example AGM batteries that would fit on my vehicle:

- [Duralast Platinum Battery 35-AGM](https://www.autozone.com/batteries-starting-and-charging/battery/duralast-platinum-battery-35-agm-group-size-35-650-cca/377104_258019_25698) (650 CCA, 55 Ah, $199.99)
- [Optima Yellowtop D35](https://www.optimabatteries.com/en-us/yellowtop-deep-cycle-battery) (620 CCA, 48 Ah, $234.99)

## Option 3: Use Parking Mode for Less Time

As an alternative to the other choices, I can increase the voltage cutoff on my dashcam in parking mode. By changing it to a higher voltage (such as 12.4V), it would no longer cycle the battery as deep. For a standard flooded lead-acid battery type, this would greatly increase the battery life. The downside is that the battery would drain to 12.4V quicker than 12.0V, thus decreasing camera recording time.

[1]:  I've seen some [sources](https://www.searsauto.com/car-care-101/different-types-of-batteries-for-your-car) online claiming AGM doesn't actually qualify as a "deep cycle" battery.